# Why is my code showing "Runtime error" on CodeForces?

Tags: java

Problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/1355/problem/A

Let's define the following recurrence:
an+1=an+minDigit(an)⋅maxDigit(an).
Here minDigit(x) and maxDigit(x) are the minimal and maximal digits in the decimal representation of x without leading zeroes. For examples refer to notes.

Your task is calculate aK for given a1 and K.

Input

The first line contains one integer t (1≤t≤1000) — the number of independent test cases.

Each test case consists of a single line containing two integers a1 and K (1≤a1≤1018, 1≤K≤1016) separated by a space.

Output

For each test case print one integer aK on a separate line.

Example:

INPUT:

8

1 4

487 1

487 2

487 3

487 4

487 5

487 6

487 7

OUTPUT:

42

487

519

528

544

564

588

628

I am getting the correct output when I run it in BlueJ on my computer but it says "Runtime error  on test 1" on Codeforces. This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class b
{
    static Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main()
    {
        long t=sc.nextLong();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            long a=sc.nextLong();
            long k=sc.nextLong();
            for(long j=1;j<k;j++){
            long c=a,min=9,max=0;
            while(c>0)
            {
                long rem=c%10;
                if(rem<min)
                min=rem;
                if(rem>max)
                max=rem;
                c=c/10;
            }
            a=a+min*max;
        }            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't properly defined your `main` method. The correct signature of a Java main method is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Code goes here
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!!